# How to Checked Some checkboxes statically with readonly in list using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code

```js
var app = angular.module('checkbox', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.array = [1, 5];
        $scope.array_ = angular.copy($scope.array);
       $scope.states=

[ 

  {"name":"AP",cities:[{"id":"101","name":"Vij"},{"id":"102","name":"Gnt"},{"id":"103","name":"Nell"}]} ,
  {"name":"TP",cities:[{"id":"104","name":"Hyd"},{"id":"105","name":"War"}]} ,   
  {"name":"UP",cities:[{"id":"106","name":"Kanpur"},{"id":"107","name":"Agra"},{"id":"107","name":"Noida"},{"id":"107","name":"Lucknow"}]} 


];

        $scope.childCheckChange = function (parent) {
          var allChecks = true;
          for (var i in parent.cities) {
              if (!parent.cities[i].isChecked) {
                  allChecks = false;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if (allChecks) {
              parent.isChecked = true;
          }
          else {
              parent.isChecked = false;
          }
      };

      $scope.checkChange = function (item) {
         // $scope.parentCheckChange(item.childmodules);
          for (var i in item.cities) {
              item.cities[i].isChecked = item.isChecked;
          }
             // childCheckChange(item.parent);
      };

    })
```

```html
<div ng-app="checkbox" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="state in states">
                                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="state.isChecked" ng-change="checkChange(state)" />
                                            <label>{{state.name}}</label>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li ng-repeat="city in state.cities">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="city.isChecked" ng-change="childCheckChange(state)" />
                                                    <label>{{city.name}}</label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <input type="button" value="Save"/>
</div>
```

In the above code I have group of checkboxes . I already developed code for when your select group checkbox by defaultly check all checkboxes in that group and also when user select all child checkboxes by defaultly that related group is checked. Now i want to show State (TP) Group checkboxes selected by defaultly with readonly at runtime and also selected Kanpur and Agra cities checkboxes from UP state with readonly. Finally when i click save button what are the checkboxes are checked get their id values. 
This is my jsFiddle.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/t7kr8/855/
```

Comment: So what problems are you having getting the defaults set? That needs to be done in your data model. There really isn't a question here

Comment: How to checked entire State(TP) Group checkboxes by defaultly with readonly